# method that can get all the integers between two given numbers in array - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Trying to build a method that can get all the integers between two given numbers.

Example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

method(2,9)
```

Should give you this output back:

```
[ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

What would be the easiest way to crack this problem ?

Comment: Why is there `arr` in addition to 2 and 9? Do you want to get all numbers in the array above 2 and below 9?

Comment: Yes from the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) with a non-inclusive range from the successor of x to y:

```
def f(x, y, z)
  z.grep(x.succ...y)
end

f(2, 9, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
# => [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: How can I put an array as a variable instead of a set array that you have put into the method ?

Comment: The same way you're using `x` and `y`, with a new argument in the method definition. See the updated answer @Tomas.R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-select) with a simple comparison:

```
arr.select { |e| 2 < e && e < 9 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def all_between(a, lower, upper)
    a & ((lower+1)..(upper-1)).to_a
 end
```

Call it as

```
 all_between(arr, 2, 9)
```